# Is there a filesystem that works on WIndows and natively on Mac with POSIX permissions?

Tags: windows, ssh, mac, filesystems, posix

I want to store my SSH keys on a USB drive and have it work on Mac and Windows. Which means I need a file system that has support for POSIX permissions so that I can use the SSH keys without copying them to another folder on my MacBook's hard drive and chmoding (due to OpenSSH Client checking the permissions on SSH keys).

I know [NTFS has POSIX permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata) and is natively supported on Windows, but not on Mac. I did try using [macFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/) and [ntfs-3g](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G), but I was never able to mount it properly.

I need either:

- A file system that works on Mac and Windows with POSIX permissions.
- Another way to mount NTFS on Mac.
- A way to prevent OpenSSH from checking permissions on SSH keys.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note the tile of the question suffers from being an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). It covers only the first of the three approaches you're considering in the body of the question. And even these three don't form a complete set of possibilities. E.g this workaround in `zsh`: `ssh -i =(cat /path/to/key) …` may be enough to conveniently work with a key stored on a USB drive. I'm not posting it as an answer because it doesn't answer the current question.

Comment: In Linux NTFS can be mounted with the option of `uid` and `gid` (often done dynamically with `udisks2`). See if similar approach is viable in macOS?

Comment: USBs are a really poor storage medium for SSH keys since permissions can be bypassed relatively easily; especially in this instance, the SSH keys should be encrypted with a complex passphrase _(a better method would be a [YubiKey](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-5-overview/) and configuring a GPG Authentication key to use as an SSH key)_. Windows supports ext-varient filesystems via Paragon's [LinuxFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/), as well as [APFS and HFS+](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/mac-toolbox/). SSH keys should always be G and O inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the XY Problem @KamilMaciorowski. Your command also did work.